# Loading table and saving as csv from Hive?

Tags: python, database, hive, sqlalchemy, export-to-csv

I have a huge 440M rows and 30 columns table.
I need to save it locally.

I have used the SQLAlchemy package to do this but it takes a lot of time.

Please advise how can I do it faster? Should I use Dask? 
Here is my code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pyhive import hive
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import *
from odo import odo

################################################################################
# Using SQLAlchemy:

# Creating engine:

engine = create_engine('hive://er123.company.test:10000/db')

# Connecting to the engine:

con = engine.connect()

# Read database and builds SQLAlchemy Table Objects:

metadata = MetaData()
tbl_name = "tbl"
Table(tbl_name, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

# Create statement:
stmt = "SELECT * FROM tbl"

# Fetch the data:
data = pd.read_sql(stmt, con = con)

# To save to a csv:
# Using SQL statement:

pd.read_sql(stmt, con = con).to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Is the table present in Hive?

Comment: Yes @SatyaPavan do you any idea?

Comment: Have you tried this option - Insert overwrite local directory '/local/path/' row format delimited FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' select * from <hive_table>